# How can i get a user's gmail contact groups using gmail oauth? (not Contacts API)

Tags: api, oauth, gmail, contacts

Is there a way i can get access to a user's contact groups using the Gmail oAuth alone? I know it is possible to do using the google contacts API, but i am already using the gmail oAuth so i dont want the user to have to authenticate contacts api separately.

Comment: The answer to the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994877/how-do-i-get-gmail-contacts-using-javascript/18731979#18731979) might help


  [1]:

Answer (score 0):

hmmm now i;m thinking that you could just oauth into both contacts and gmail of them somehow specifying a double scope parameter...
or just writing the program to do one after another.

Comment: Add both scopes into a string and use that in the scopes entry when getting the authorization - that way the user only authorizes once but is asked if they can authorize both the Gmail and contacts.